# как выбрать все элементы в выбранных элементах DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

может быть кто-то задавал подобный вопрос, но я даже не понимаю как его сформулировать и гуглю уже часа два. у меня есть несколько форм на странице с одинаковым классом и есть в этих формах несколько инпутов так же все с одинаковыми классами. как мне выбрать в формах все инпуты и засунуть в переменную? я делал так:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__form');
const inputs = forms.forEach((el) => {
    el.querySelectorAll('.popup__input')
})
```

по запросу

```
console.log(forms)
```

он выдает правильный результат со всеми DOM элементами, содержащий данный класс, а при

```
console.log(inputs)
```

выдает undefined.
пробовал вообще даже

```
const inputs = forms.querySelectorAll('.popup__input')
```

но так он пытается ее прочесть как функцию почему-то и выдает, соответственно, ошибку.

Comment: метод `forEach` возвращает `undefined`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как выбрать все элементы в выбранных элементах DOM

В вашем случае, вот так:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__form .popup__input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых у вас ошибка в том, что `querySelectorAll` возвращает `NodeList`, а не массив. У них методы отличаются. Можете посмотреть, как преобразовать его в массив, способов много.

Во-вторых, вы используете `forEach` для наполнения переменной `inputs` при инициализации, но в самом теле `forEach` ничего не сохраняете. Возможно, вы хотели использовать `map` или `reduce` у массива.

Конечно проще сделать селектор, выбирающий элементы с классом `popup__input` из элементов с классом `popup__form`

Вот так

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__form .popup__input');
```

Но для интереса и изучения языка, ваш код будет работать, если сделать вот так **(но лучше так не делать, другое дело если у вас не коллекция HTML элементов)**

```js
const inputs = [...forms].reduce((items, el) => [
    ...items,
    ...el.querySelectorAll('.popup__input')
], []);
```

Comment: спасибо! да, действительно забыл, что прежде, чем использовать forEach надо было преобразовать nodelist в массив. однако вторую часть ответа мне не совсем ясна либо я не понял, что вы хотели сказать. почему после вызова callback функции у вас начинаются такие [] скобки? и не понял, что вы имели ввиду в строке
`...items,`

Comment: Вообще, про ...items можете почитать вот тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax


Про () => [], () => {} можете почитать вот тут тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Чуть позже я обновлю ответ с пояснениями механики работы второго варианта реализации, но учитывайте, что такой вариант лучше не использовать. Он еще будет актуален, если у нас какие-то другие объекты, просто показал принцип.